# Text file isn't updating

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$fi = "/home2/chippery/public_html/rtf/webR/top.txt";
$fih = fopen($fi, 'w');
$cont = $_POST["top"];
fwrite($fih,$cont);
fclose($fih);


$fi = "/home2/chippery/public_html/rtf/webR/bottom.txt";
$fih = fopen($fi, 'w');
$cont = $_POST["bottom"];
fwrite($fih,$cont);
fclose($fih);


$fi = "/home2/chippery/public_html/rtf/webR/nextTime.txt";
$fih = fopen($fi, 'w');
$cont = $_POST["time"];
fwrite($fih,$cont);
fclose($fih);
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Chipperyman573</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/fav.ico" />
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="change.html">
  Top: <input type="text" name="top" /><br>
  Bottom: <input type="text" name="bottom" /><br>
  Time (MS): <input type="text" name="time" /><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have already made the text pages, and when I try to use this form the pages don't change. What am I doing wrong? I'm *incredibly* new to html/php so I'm sure it's something stupid.

Comment: semicolon missing at `fopen` and `$_POST['top']`...

Comment: You are not writing the content to the file. Use `fwrite($fih,$cont)`

Comment: You should enable error reporting.

Answer (score 3):

For writing content in file you should use [`fwrite()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) after opening the file in write mode.

And in your code few mistakes are there, updated code is here. I have supposed your file name is `myfile.php`-

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$fi = "top.txt";
$fih = fopen($fi, 'w');
$cont = $_POST["top"];
fwrite($fih,$cont);
fclose($fih);


$fi = "bottom.txt";
$fih = fopen($fi, 'w');
$cont = $_POST["bottom"];
fwrite($fih,$cont);
fclose($fih);


$fi = "nextTime.txt";
$fih = fopen($fi, 'w');
$cont = $_POST["time"];
fwrite($fih,$cont);
fclose($fih);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Chipperyman573</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/fav.ico" />
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="myfile.php">
  Top: <input type="text" name="top" /><br>
  Bottom: <input type="text" name="bottom" /><br>
  Time (MS): <input type="text" name="time" /><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still doesn't update. It refreshes the page when I click the button but the page doesn't update.

Comment: @chipperyman573 what you want to do? I thought you want to update the text file.

Comment: Yeah and it isn't. I just want to replace text and nothing is happening.

Comment: When you are submitting the page, than it is not updating the content of file?

Comment: I click the submit button.

Comment: Yes for updating the file, you need to submit the form by clicking on the submit button. It will not update the file on page load.

Comment: Yeah I clicked the button, didn't hit enter. The text files are in the same directory (`/public_html/[path]/top.txt` and `/public_html/[path]/update.html`)

Comment: and one more thing is missing there. pls give `action="filename.php"` in the form tag. where `filename.php` is the file where you have putted above php code. My be it's the problem. and let me know the file is getting updated or not

Comment: (Sorry if you saw old message I misclicked). And that returns with a 404 page when I hit the button. `Edit:` Updated to the correct webpage and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't update the page. I get no error, the page refreshes and whatnot. It just doesn't update.

Comment: check out the file permission of txt files, this may be also the problem. file should have permission with 777

Comment: They weren't 777 so I updated them and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I updated it and that still doesn't work. I don't see why not though.

Comment: try to give absolute file name like if file is on the location `c:\folder\file.txt` than give `c:\\folder\\file.txt`. Other than it should work.

Comment: I changed it to `$fi = "//home2//chippery//public_html//rtf//webR//change.html//top.txt";`, like that? It doesn't work. It's not on my computer it's on a shared hosting sever.

Comment: no if you are using linux env. just give `/home2/chippery/public_html/rtf/webR/top.txt`

Comment: Changed to `$fi = "/home2/chippery/public_html/rtf/webR/top.txt";`. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use the **file_put_contents()** function.

> This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose()
>   successively to write data to a file.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fi = "top.txt";
    $cont = $_POST["top"];
    file_put_contents($fi, $cont);


    $fi = "bottom.txt";
    $cont = $_POST["bottom"];
    file_put_contents($fi, $cont);


    $fi = "nextTime.txt";
    $cont = $_POST["time"];
    file_put_contents($fi, $cont);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$fi = "top.txt";
$fih = fopen($fi, 'w') <-- missing semi-colon
$cont = $_POST["top"] <-- missing semi-colon
fclose($fih);


$fi = "bottom.txt";
$fih = fopen($fi, 'w') <-- missing semi-colon
$cont = $_POST["bottom"];
fclose($fih);


$fi = "nextTime.txt";
$fih = fopen($fi, 'w') <-- missing semi-colon
$cont = $_POST["time"];
fclose($fih);
}
?>
```

And as Ritesh said, you aren't writing any data to your files. Just opening, and closing them.